# Android (libGDX) http connection with mySQL using PHP server side scripting

Tags: java, php, mysql, android-studio, libgdx

I am trying to connect my libGDX(java) android project with a mySQL database through a server side PHP scripting in order to implement a login process using POST method (this includes a username and password).

Therefore, i am facing unexpectable problems. For your info i am using XAMPP and APACHE web server locally.

What i am facing! Some times the PHP script sends back the following response string, as if not recognizing the POST parameters (despite the fact that POST message includes them and contain values (string)!!):

```
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: username in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\login\login.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: password in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\login\login.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
```

Some other, the debugger (on Android studio) which is enabled to show me the debugging logs, stops displaying any log after pressing 2-5 times the btnclickLogin() (is shown below), which implements the login activity.

This sounds to me that http connection hangs up and maybe the click button's listener does not respones any more!!!

The more strange one, is that SOMETIMES the same code, returns "success" and everything works fine.

The android code is the next

```
private void btnclickLogin() {

//Getting values from edit texts
    Gdx.app.setLogLevel(Application.LOG_DEBUG);

    final String username = usernamefld.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = passwordfld.getText().toString().trim();

    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    parameters.put("username", username);
    parameters.put("password", password);

    Gdx.app.debug("Login process started.", "Username=/" + username + "/  Password=/" + password + "/");

    HttpRequestBuilder requestBuilder = new HttpRequestBuilder();
    HttpRequest httpRequest;

   httpRequest = requestBuilder.newRequest().method(Net.HttpMethods.POST).url("http://192.168.1.2/login/login.php").content(HttpParametersUtils.convertHttpParameters(parameters)).build();
    httpRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    httpRequest.setTimeOut(6000);

    Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest(httpRequest, new HttpResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void handleHttpResponse(Net.HttpResponse httpResponse) {
            String status = httpResponse.getResultAsString().trim();
            Gdx.app.debug("Return result by the server=", status);

            if(status.contains("success"))
                game.setScreen(new StartingScreen(game));
        }

        @Override
        public void failed(Throwable t) {

            String status = "failed";
            Gdx.app.debug("Connection failed due to the next error:", t.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelled() {
        }
    });

    httpRequest.reset();
    Gdx.app.debug("Exiting", "From login button function");

}
```

PHP scripts are

For login.php

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
  //Getting values
  session_start();
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

//Creating sql query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";

//importing dbConnect.php script
require_once('dbConnect.php');

//executing query
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

//fetching result
$check = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

//if we got some result
if(isset($check)){
   //displaying success
   echo "success";
}else{
   //displaying failure
   echo "failure";
}
mysqli_close($con); }?>
```

For dbConnect.php

```
<?php
   define('HOST',"localhost");
   define('USER',"root");
   define('PASS',"");
   define('DB',"userlogging");
   $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error);
  $con->set_charset("utf8");   ?>
```

Please give a hand to overcome this problem and make the http connection "stable"!!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you check what all values you are getting in `$_SERVER` on your php script by using `print_r($_SERVER)`

Answer (score 0):

Mishra sorry for the latest of my reply.

Yes, actually i have placed a print_r to see the values that come up to PHP script and found that both parameters were missing.

After so much searches on the internet and alternative solutions that found, i have not found out why does it happen.  So, i replaced the HttpRequestBuilder.

Finally, in order to have a complete working code, i used the next and everything works fine now.

```
 final String username = usernamefld.getText().toString().trim();
 final String password = passwordfld.getText().toString().trim();

 Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
 parameters.put("username", username);
 parameters.put("password", password);
 final HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest(Net.HttpMethods.POST);
 httpRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 httpRequest.setHeader("Upgrade", "HTTP/1.1, HTTP/2.0, SHTTP/1.3, IRC/6.9, RTA/x11");
 httpRequest.setUrl(LOGIN_URL);
 httpRequest.setContent(HttpParametersUtils.convertHttpParameters(parameters));
 httpRequest.setTimeOut(6000);
```

Thanks again for your help.